# If "knob" means a round/rotating element, then what is this thing called?

Tags: single-word-requests

At first sight, this question might seem to be Computer-Science-only, but in real life, this used to be on old TV sets to adjust the volume, brightness etc. So what was it called?

```
Slider object      What is this thing called? 
| \                It can move to the left and right to adjust the value.
|  |               |
V  V               V
[=================[ ]=========]
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's the word you used: a slider.

Comment: ... see [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slider?q=Slider).

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought someone would say that. :) But then how do you distinguish the whole thing from its moving part? We need different words for these.

Comment: Although the dictionaries say a 'knob' is a round shape, I don't think anyone would think twice if you call it a 'slider knob'.

Comment: Well, I had known about the words handle and thumb, but I thought they were IT terms. Would normal people use them too?

Comment: Normal people don't know the word for this thing.

Comment: @PeterShor: By which you imply there ***is*** a word specifically identifying what I would simply call ***the slider button*** (or ***knob***, [both are perfectly common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slider+knob%2Cslider+button&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cslider%20knob%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cslider%20button%3B%2Cc0)). Feasibly the people who design / manufacture such components have some unusual word, but I can't see why they would need to create a domain-specific term when normal English works just fine.

Comment: The proposed "duplicate" seems only relevant to computer GUI on-screen controls. Hardly anyone would call the moving part of a TV or radio sliding volume control a "**thumb**". Just because it's not a **radio** button (again, specialized GUI terminology) doesn't mean it's not a "button".